# Is there a way to pass \r\n as command line arguments for a C programm?

Tags: command-line, command-line-arguments

I want to check the end of a string passed as a command line argument for a C program. The end should contain the spacial characters \r\n. What I do is that I write the string between quotation marks after the program like that:

```
./program_name "String"
```

I wonder if there exists a ways to pass \r\n at the end of that string.
If I just wrote:

```
./program_name "String\r\n"
```

I still don't get the return I expect for comparing the last two characters of the string with '\r' and '\n'. Here is the segment of code I am checking it with:

```
char * request_line = argv[1];
size_t sizeOfReq = strlen(request_line);
else if(request_line[sizeOfReq-1] != '\n' && request_line[sizeOfReq-2] != '\r') {


 printf("He couldn't just do that!\n");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: If you pass the string like this "String\\r\\n" the input string will be "String\r\n", but \n and \t will be strings of two chars ton special chars.I don't know if i helped.

Comment: How is the program being started, from another program, from a shell prompt, ...? Which OS?

Comment: The program is independent. I start it from the shell in Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: Try with `./program_name $'String\r\n'`

Comment: Thank you, that did it. Would you explain what the $ is for in a new answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\r\n` are not special characters. This is just a convention. A backslash followed by a character is interpreted by some software as an escape sequence. In your case, the C compiler translates the two character sequence `\r` to a one character carriage return and the two character sequence `\n` to a one character line feed.

So, you depend on someone converting the escape sequence to the corresponding real character.

Now you have two options: add code in your program to handle the escape sequence conversion or make the caller generate the real characters.

In linux, the arguments given to a process are created by the program that invokes the process. If you are using the bash shell to start the process, you can use (read [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings))

```
./program_name $'String\r\n'
```

indicating to bash that the string includes C like strings that needs to be parsed.

Other shells can have their own sytax/rules.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
./program_name "String\r\n"
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I need, I need to pass the special characters \r\n. I will update my question to clarify that applying your solution doesn't return the desired result.